# How to subtract an isize from a usize?

Tags: types, rust, type-conversion, primitive

I've got a `usize` that does hit very large values. I also apply a delta to it that I receive in the form of an `isize`. What's the best way to apply the delta without losing any precision?

```
fn main() {
    let mut big_indexer: usize = 4295032832; // 2^32 + 2^16
    let delta: isize = -65792; // 2^16 + 2^8

    let big_indexer = (big_indexer as isize) + delta // Can't do this b/c overflow
    let big_indexer = big_indexer + (delta as usize) // Can't do this b/c lose negative number

    // This is ugly
    if delta < 0 {
        let big_indexer -= delta.abs() as usize;
    } else {
        let big_indexer += delta.abs() as usize;
    }
}
```

Comment: `delta.abs()` may panic when `delta` is `isize::MIN`.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways:

- either you keep all your value in range of `isize` (the choice of rust `std` for example)
- or you only work with `usize` and handle sign yourself (clearly my preferred choice).

But the implementation is up to you; for example, you could have a `bool` that tells you if the offset is a difference or an addition, or use an enum:

```rust
fn foo(n: usize, offset: usize, sub: bool) -> Option<usize> {
    (if sub {
        usize::checked_sub
    } else {
        usize::checked_add
    })(n, offset)
}

enum OffSet {
    Neg(usize),
    Pos(usize),
}

fn bar(n: usize, offset: OffSet) -> Option<usize> {
    match offset {
        OffSet::Pos(offset) => n.checked_add(offset),
        OffSet::Neg(offset) => n.checked_sub(offset),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let n = 4295032832; // 2^32 + 2^16
    let offset = 65792; // 2^16 + 2^8
    let sub = true;
    assert_eq!(Some(n - offset), foo(n, offset, sub));
    assert_eq!(Some(n - offset), bar(n, OffSet::Neg(offset)));
}
```

This is not ugly at all; you just have to use some trait to hide the logic and then you just have to use it.

Comment: You could create an `Offset` from an `isize`

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios the point is to get rid of `isize`, also use `isize` lead to overflow problem when value is `isize::min_value`, I have a strong opinion on that, life is better without isize

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=69496ca61b32a3c369a445cbe85fce84

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios yes but you run into another problem what to do when your offset is bigger or less then `isize` limit ?

Comment: What do you mean? i was talking about `isize` -> `Offset` conversion.

Answer (score 6):

### Rust 1.66 (stable release on December 15, 2022)

As of Rust 1.66 the standard library now has [`checked_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.checked_add_signed), [`overflowing_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.overflowing_add_signed), [`saturating_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.saturating_add_signed), and [`wrapping_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.wrapping_add_signed).

### Rust 1.13 (September 10, 2020)*

The easiest way is to create your own `add_signed` function or trait. Here is what that function would look like. This implementation should give optimal performance in release mode while also properly handling overflow checks (if enabled). When compiled by rustc in release mode (overflow checks disabled) this function produced the same assembly as `a.wrapping_add(b as usize)`.

```rust
#[track_caller]
#[inline(always)]
pub const fn add_signed(a: usize, b: isize) -> usize {
    match b {
        x if x < 0 => a - x.wrapping_abs() as usize,
        x => a + x as usize
    }
}
```

* To become fully compatible with Rust 1.13, you must remove `#[track_caller]` and convert it to a non-`const` function.

Answer (score 4):

[Stargateur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59209602/3650362) is fine advice in general, but let's suppose you can't just rewrite the API to eliminate `isize`s, or limit the range of your `usize`s. In such a situation you may cast `delta` to `usize` and explicitly use wrapping arithmetic:

```
// DON'T COPY THIS LINE unless you read the caveat below first
big_indexer = big_indexer.wrapping_add(delta as usize);
```

This works for the example in the question, but it has a "big" caveat: if both `delta` and `big_indexer` are positive and their sum would overflow, it wraps instead. If the numbers you're using are guaranteed to be in range, that's fine. If you need to add an `isize` to a `usize` *and* detect overflow, you're back to an "ugly" `if` expression.

```rust
fn add_offset(big_indexer: usize, delta: isize) -> Option<usize> {
    if delta < 0 {
        big_indexer.checked_sub(delta.wrapping_abs() as usize)
    } else {
        big_indexer.checked_add(delta as usize)
    }
}
```

If you use wrapping arithmetic a lot, you may want to use the [`std::num::Wrapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html) struct to make it more convenient.